# NBA Jam PS3/XBox 360 Multiplayer

Tags: nba-jam-2010

What will NBA Jam's multiplayer options be on the PS3 and XBox 360 when it is released? E.g. will four local players be able to control a player each? Will two local players be able to play on the same team against another team online?

A Google search brings up a lot of references to "2-on-2 multiplayer" but I'm not sure if that's referring to the number of people who can play the game, or the fact that the game that you're playing is a 2-on-2 game of basketball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [his video on Destructoid](http://www.destructoid.com/the-features-of-nba-jam-on-xbox-360-and-playstation-3-187864.phtml) (37 seconds in), it looks like with an update to the game, you will be able to do any of the online multiplayer with a mixture of online and friends locally